# Resize NTFS volume while it is in use

Tags: windows, partitioning, ntfs, storage-spaces, virtual-disk

I've created a partition over a Storage Spaces virtual disk and formatted it as a NTFS volume. Here are the powershell commands I used:

```
$partition = (New-Partition -DiskNumber 9 -Size 300GB)
Format-Volume -Partition $partition -FileSystem NTFS -AllocationUnitSize 16384
Add-PartitionAccessPath -DiskNumber 9 -PartitionNumber $partition.PartitionNumber -AccessPath M:
```

Can I resize the partition while it is being used? Or should I disconnect the server (take it offline) before resizing it?

A quick experiment showed that a partition can be resized via Windows' extend API or diskpart, while it is in use. I'd like to list and handle the gotchas (if there are any).

Answer (score 0):

You can resize a live partition using the Resize-Partition Commandlet
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/storage/resize-partition?view=win10-ps

this is not to be confused with 
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/hyper-v/resize-vhd?view=win10-ps
that can be used on certain VHDX files when live. but not universally